# Restrict a user to a set of documents in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with many documents. In my app, a login happens under a username. For a user only a group of data should be visible, that is I want to restrict each user to a set of documents. Can somebody offer a solution of how to implement this using elasticsearch?.

Suppose my index contain the follwing documents
record1
record2
record3
record4
And I have say 2 users, user1 and user2
When the user1 is logged in, he should have access to "record1","record2" and "record3". Where for user2 , the access should only be to "record4".

Comment: You should check out [Shield](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/index.html) which should provide pretty much what you need to fulfill your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can add one more column to the index where in you can persist the intended user for the record and while querying the index you can check if the logged in user in among the users specified in the column.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use a [index aliases](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html).
Index aliases has the capability to add filter to them.

So create 2 aliases , one for each user.

Now for each alias , create a filter which restricts the user to his own set of documents. ( Just use a document ID search )

Restrict these users to use only these aliases using a proxy. 
That should do the trick